# "No gradients provided for any variable" error when switching from Sequential to layers using Functional API in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I receive a "ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['dense_1/kernel:0', 'dense_1/bias:0']." with complex or simple (below) models that worked fine when used with Sequential. I have tried a variety of layers, optimizers, and datasets. Same error occurs when using real data or the random numbers below.

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from numpy.random  import rand
from keras.optimizers import SGD

def build_model(input):    
       input_layer = keras.layers.Input(batch_input_shape=input)
       Dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(16)(input_layer)
       model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[Dense_layer])
       return model 

x_val_multi=rand(418, 4, 13, 1, 1)

model = build_model((x_val_multi).shape)

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(opt, loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error']) 
history = model.fit(x_val_multi,validation_split=0.4)
```

Comment: Can you include a complete self-contained example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can try changing the parameter `input` to something different because `input` is also a built-in Python function; also try using `shape` instead of `batch_input_shape`. Secondly you may try adding some activation function to `dense_layer` (for example 'sigmoid' as you are using `mae` as loss function).

Comment: Thanks! I added activation='sigmoid' to the Dense layer and changed the name of the input but still got the same "No gradients provided" error. If I use shape instead of batch_input_shape I get the error: expected shape=(None, 418, 4, 13, 1, 1), found shape=(None, 4, 13, 1, 1).

Comment: Oh, you don't have label data. Try making one. If you use `shape` instead of `batch_input_shape` then use `build_model((x_val_multi).shape[1:])`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, Tung. That did the trick. This works now:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from numpy.random  import rand
from keras.optimizers import SGD

def build_model(data_input):    
    input_layer = keras.layers.Input(shape=data_input)
    Dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(16,activation='sigmoid')(input_layer)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_layer], outputs=[Dense_layer])
    return model 

data=rand(418, 4, 13, 1, 1)
labels=rand(418, 4, 13, 1, 1)

model = build_model((x_val_multi).shape[1:])

opt = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.1)
model.compile(opt, loss='mean_absolute_error', metrics=['mean_absolute_error']) 
history = model.fit(data, labels)
```